# MS SQL Server Dates Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, datetime, odbc

I have data this is linked from SQL Server into an excel document. The column format on the SQL Server is `datetime2`.

When I get the data via an ODBC connection it comes across as a string?

I tried using

```
CAST(column AS DATE )
```

but that didn't work.

I tried reformatting via

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column, 103)
```

as well but that didn't work.

I tried retrieving the data via Microsoft query as well but that didn't work.

At the moment I am using VBA code like:

```
While (ActiveCell.Value <> "")
  ActiveCell.Value = DATEVALUE(ActiveCell.Value)
  ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Activate
Wend
```

and looping through each column that needs this treatment but 100000 rows in multiple columns takes forever to loop through. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You might find this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578633/sql-string-in-vba-in-excel-2010-with-dates) helpful.  If you stick with your current method make sure `ScreenUpdating=False` is set before your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Excel and Access as well don't like the SQL Server datetime2 format.

I have converted the data into datetime format and that seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert date in the Excel to the following format:

> "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"

This is the [default ODBC canonical format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). In this case the implicit conversion will be made and the correct results will be achieved.

Another way is to try to perform convert using another style:

> CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column, 120)

Answer (score 0):

No MACRO's required, us Excel table columns instead.

Any ODBC connections in Excel returns a Table. 
Simply add a new column to the right of your table with a calculation.
It should look something like this 
=DATEVALUE([@DateColumnFromODBC])

The column will add and shrink with your table and always retain it's reference as long as the ODBC connection stays the same.